# How to merge htaccess redirect by language function with www to non www and http to https? browsers return: err_too_many_redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https, no-www

i must get to work this 3 conditions because my website works on both english and spanish, depending the browser it must redirect to spanish or stay in english and i need to  get sure that all my visitors reach it no matter they access via www or non www and has to always point to https in ES or EN scenario

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://mywebsite/es/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(en|es)/?$ index.html?lang=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Please state the URLs you are trying to redirect from/to. You currently have no "http to https" redirect in your `.htaccess` file to merge with? But there is no need to "merge" them (in fact, you should not "merge" the language redirect) - just have them as separate rules. But language "redirects" in general are bad for users/SEO.

Comment: thank´s for the answer, so the best practice should be to ask user to manually set their propper language?

Comment: Yes, having "guessed" what their preferred language might be. Don't "force" it - as it could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: my speech doesn't answer your question directly.

As previous comment mentioned, language redirects are suboptimal practice. The best way (and the one recommended by Google) is:

- Step 1: at first visit guess user's language based on IP and browser language,
- Step 2 (absolutely required step): show your guess to user (in a popup) and beg him to confirm your guess or to set his correct language,
- Step3: After user action set a cookie with language selection, and on further visits redirect him according to htis cookie.

Googlebot gets no cookies - it should crawl different language versions ONLY based on hreflang links.

Comment: thanks for the suggstión i will try that and update my question

Comment: finally i follow your sugestion and deleted redirection via htaccess and used cokkies to improve SEO and it work fine.